# Is it possible to dump input file?

Tags: ida

Similarly to `retrieve_input_file_md5`, I was looking for a way to dump a patched input file.

Basically, I would like to do the following:

- patch the file in IDA
- dump the patched input file to another file
- try the resulting file in an emulator (it's a PSX BIOS)

Is this possible from within IDA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the code in IDA. IDA saves internally the original as well as the patched content.

Make your modifications using the sub menu commands of **Edit -> Patch program**

If your modifications are completed you can apply the modifications on an external file. To do so use menu **Edit -> Patch program -> Apply patches to input file**. 
It allows you to select an external file and apply the changes you have made to it.